NestJS e2e test jwt
i have a test for nestjs login endpoint. but i have en error.
Could you please some help?
My test file:


import { Test, TestingModule } from "@nestjs/testing";
import { UsersController } from "./users.controller";
import { UsersService } from "./users.service";
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersModule } from "./users.module";
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { CreateUserDto } from "./dto/createUser.dto";

describe('first test', () => { 

    let usersController: UsersController;
    let usersService: UsersService;
    let app: INestApplication;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [UsersModule],
          })
            .overrideProvider(UsersService)
            .useValue(usersService)
            .compile();
      
          app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
          await app.init();
      });


    it('/POST create', async () => {
        const createUserDto = new CreateUserDto();
        createUserDto.username = "deneme";
        createUserDto.password = "102030";
    
        // Act
        const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
          .post(`/users/create`)
          .send(createUserDto);
    
        expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
    });

 });



My users.service.ts :


import { HttpException, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectModel } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Model, Types } from "mongoose";
import { CreateUserDto } from "./dto/createUser.dto";
import { FollowUserDto } from "./dto/followUser.dto";
import { LoginUserDto } from "./dto/loginUser.dto";
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { JwtService } from "@nestjs/jwt";
import { Users } from "src/schemas/user.schema";

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(Users.name) private userModel: Model<Users>,
        private jwtService: JwtService
    ) {}

    async loginUser(loginUserDto: LoginUserDto) {
        
        const {username, password} = loginUserDto
        
        const user = await this.userModel.findOne({username});
        if (!user) {
            
            throw new HttpException("User Not Found", 400);
        }

        const passMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        if (!passMatch) {
            
            throw new HttpException("User Pass Does not match", 400);
        }

        return this.generateUserToken(user);
    }

    async generateUserToken(user) {
        const accessToken = this.jwtService.sign({user}, {expiresIn: '1h'});

        return accessToken;

    }

    async createUser(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
        const {username, password} = createUserDto;
        const usernameInUse = await this.userModel.findOne({username});
        if (usernameInUse) {
            throw new HttpException("Username In Use", 400);
        }

        const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        await this.userModel.create({
            username,
            password: hashedPass
        });

        return true;
    }

    async followUser(followUserDto: FollowUserDto, userId: string) {
        const myInfo = await this.userModel.findById(userId);
        if (!myInfo) {
            throw new HttpException("My Info Not Found", 400);
        }

        const followUserInfo = await this.userModel.findById(followUserDto.followId);
        if (!followUserInfo) {
            throw new HttpException("Followed User Info Not Found", 400);
        }


        const myInfoResult = await this.userModel.updateOne({_id: myInfo._id}, {
            $push: {
              follows: followUserInfo,
            },
          });

          return myInfoResult;
    }
}



The error is :

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (UsersModel, ?). Please make sure that the argument JwtService at index [1] is available in the UsersModule context.


you'll need to show us the UsersModule's definition. We can only say that the JwtService provider is not registered in there

Like Micael Levi said in the comment, having the definition of the UsersModule would help us to see the problem.
But I think the problem come from this part
.overrideProvider(UsersService)
.useValue(usersService)

You override the default value of the UsersService in the UsersModule with a custom value.
The problem is that the value you give (the variable usersService) is undefined. So the module will not be able to use it.
If you want to keep using this variable you will need to instantiate the UsersService yourself with the correct dependencies. Something like this:
let usersService = new UsersService(*The user model (from mongoose?)*, new JwtService());

It should works, as long as you manage to get the user model correctly (I don't know how Mongoose works so can't help here)
BUT
With your current tests I don't really see the points of overriding the UserService. Usually, we override a service when we need to change the behavior of something.
For example, imagine you run your tests without a DB because you just want to test the JS part. You can override the service with another one to prevent the service from sending DB requests.
But in your case you seems (for now) to just test the normal behavior. So if that's the case you should not override anything and just build the module normally.
const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [UsersModule],
          }).compile();

And in the case you just want to use the UsersService directly in your test without sending a HTTP request, you can get the instance directly from the app, without instantiating it by hand, like this:
const usersService = app.get(UsersService)
